# Access inserted element from unordered_map::emplace return value

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

I'm calling `unordered_map::emplace()` and I am storing the returned value (a pair). I just want to access the inserted value from the pair but for the life of me I cannot figure out the correct configuration of this confusing pair.

My unordered map definition:

```
std::unordered_map<GUID, shared_ptr<Component>> components;
```

I've looked at the `unordered_map::emplace()` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace); according to this the first element in the pair should be the `shared_ptr<Component>` but the compiler is just not happy.

In the below code I get the error: `Error   2   error C2227: left of '->gUid' must point to class/struct/union/generic type`

```
class Component {
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Params>
    GUID addComponent(Params... params)
    {
        auto cmp = Component::create<T>(params...);
        auto res = components.emplace(cmp->gUid, cmp);

        if (!res.second) {
            GUID gUid;
            getNullGUID(&gUid);
            return gUid;
        }

        return (*res.first)->gUid; // compiler error here
        // *Yes I know I can do: return cmp->gUid;
    }

    GUID gUid; // initialised in constructor
    std::unordered_map<GUID, std::shared_ptr<Component>> components;
};
```

Any idea how to correctly access the pairs second value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `first` of the pair returned from `emplace` is an *iterator* -- which, for unordered_map, acts like a pointer to a `pair<key, value>`.  So to get the value from *that* pair, you need `second`:

```
return res.first->second->gUid;
```